Answer that was deleted by a moderator was undeleted by normal users; why was it allowed and can it be fixed?
Since 2011, normal users have been prevented from voting to undelete posts that were deleted by moderators.
However, today, this answer was undeleted by votes from normal users after having been deleted by a moderator.
It appears that a bug was introduced when the logic for checking if a post was mod-deleted was changed to fix a bug that prevented users from voting to undelete posts that were voted for deletion by a normal user who later became a moderator.
Why is this happening, and can it please be fixed? Is it because the answer was deleted implicitly as a result of being converted to an edit rather than explicitly?
(To be clear, my undelete vote was purely for testing purposes, as was the one cast afterwards - I found it extremely strange that a mod-deleted post had an undelete vote, so I tested to see if it'd accept my vote and it did. I then asked in chat for a third vote to see if it'd actually get undeleted.)

Is text of the form "appended answer 404140 as supplemental" which appears in an Edit Summary an indication that a moderator was able to use a tool to automatically append an answer into an edit of the question? I have seen such an edit summary before, but wasn't sure if the moderator had to manually edit the question.

@ChesterGillon Yes - see [tag:convert-to-edit].

Doesn't seem to be related to convert-to-edit. This question's got an undelete vote despite me deleting it unilaterally.

@Spevacus FYI, just for testing purposes, I was apparently able to successfully add a second undelete vote to that question you linked to which you had deleted.

I did the same for the corresponding question: I saw a few close votes so I just piled up on it, without considering whether the question should actually be closed. I'm trying my best to understand how voting votes on SE

@Spevacus It isn't just you. I was also able to vote to undelete this answer deleted by a moderator with longer tenure.

@FranckDernoncourt I don't really understand you're comment. How does voting vote? However, definetly never see "a few close votes" and pile "up on it, without considering whether the question should actually be closed".

@Starship he means he voted to close his own question (see revisions), and he did it without intending to actually close, probably not knowing it will actually be counted. And the last sentence in the comment should have been "how voting works on SE". (Guess he can flag the comment asking a mod to edit, but not sure mods will actually do it)

Thank you for your quick report about the regression! We reused the same logic which was determining to whom to show the former moderator badges and hadn't noticed that this excludes current moderators.
Apologies for the mistake. It should be fixed now!

Nice, can you perhaps post another answer just for test, and delete it? Then we can try to undelete to see if it's really fixed. :-)

eh, I cast undelete vote on your deleted answer. Perhaps because it's self deleted, it doesn't check if author is mod?

Oh... it turns out there are some users which got the moderator status without being elected or appointed. I wasn't aware of that as even the employees get the status through being appointed to a moderator without an election (that's the case also for me on other sites). However, here I'm a special snowflake and I don't have the typical user history entries. I'll look into that!

@ShadowWizard Mods can self delete in situations normal folks can't, and it'll disallow folks from voting to undelete like if they had deleted someone else's post. Obviously that's not working right now, but...

@marrados Another potential regression: if a post was deleted by a mod whose account was later deleted.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I have to imagine that might be a tough case to handle. I dunno how much info they retain on deleted users. If they discard user history it'll be tough to enforce.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog is that a regression? I don't think it was always allowed to undelete those if the deleting moderator deleted the account (I hope this sentence makes sense). I agree it could be handled better.

@marrados I voted to undelete posts that were deleted by mods who'd later deleted their accounts, so yes, it is a regression.
